# Redirect to different component based on login status

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to solve issue with redirection in react-router v4. I want to redirect to Dashboard component if user is logged in and to signup component when user is logged out if I got to path="/".

```
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />    
   <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}></PrivateRoute>
   <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
 </Switch>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
authenticate() {
    //do something to check if logged in
    if (loggedIn) {
         this.setState({ isAuth: true })
    }
}    

<Router>
    <Switch>
            <Route path="/" render={props => ( 
                <Login 
                auth={this.authenticate} 
                /> 
            )}/>
            {this.state.isAuth ?
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                />
            ) : <Redirect to='/' />}
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

and then in your login component do something like:

```
<Link to="/dashboard"><button onClick={() => this.props.auth()}>Sign In</button></Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the cases are:

1. An authenticated user visits login page => redirect to dashboard
2. An unauthenticated user visits dashboard => redirect to login page
3. An unauthenticated user visits (or redirected to) 404 => redirect to
   login page
4. An unauthenticated user logged out => redirect to login page

For 1, check  in `componentDidMount` of `login` if user is authenticated, if yes redirect to dashboard.

For 2, and 3 again in `componentDidMount`, this time if user is not authenticated, redirect to login.

And for 4, inside the `logout` redirect to user to `login` page.

I don't know how you store the authentication data, so I cannot provide the exact sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if user is logged in `PrivateRoute` and depending of this value redirect to "/login" page or return Component from props

Example of PrivateRoute component:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    isLoggedIn: makeSelectIsLoggedIn(),
});

@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {isLoggedIn} = this.props;

        return isLoggedIn
            ? <AppLayout {...this.props}/>
            : <Redirect to={routePaths.LOGIN}/>;
    }
}
```

PublicRoute component:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    isLoggedIn: makeSelectIsLoggedIn(),
});

@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class PublicRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {isLoggedIn} = this.props;

        return isLoggedIn
            ? <Redirect to={routePaths.DASHBOARD}/>
            : <AppLayout {...this.props}/>;
    }
}
```

And routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={routePaths.ROOT} component={Login} />
    <PublicRoute path={routePaths.LOGIN} component={Login}/>
    <PrivateRoute path={routePaths.DASHBOARD} component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```